# How to read every key on Keyboard?

Tags: c, linux, keyboard, ascii

How can we read the ascii of every key in the keyboard?

I used `getch()` which reads `delete`and other such keys.. But doesnt read `FN keys` or `Numlock` or anykeys that are global shortcuts..

So how can I capture those keys in the C program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three cases mentioned:

1. <kbd>delete</kbd>, etc.,
2. *FN keys* (function keys)
3. NumLock (special keys)

In the context of Linux, [`getch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html) refers to an ncurses function. If you are using ncurses, then you can tell it to decode function keys (which send a series of characters) and return those as a single number (which happens to be too large to fit in a `char`).  For example

```
int ch;
keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
ch = getch();
```

*NumLock* is a different case, because it (like the <kbd>control</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd> keys) is used as a *modifier* and normally sends no characters itself:

- The X Window environment uses it like this — and *it* can read the underlying [*scancode*](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html) directly.  X programs (such as `xterm`), can read the X events which have this information.  The source code of [`xev`](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xev/) is a good place to start in this case.
- in a console environment, one can use Linux-specific calls to read the data.  If you really need that, the [console_ioctl(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_ioctl.4.html) manual page is a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks. That was insightful :). On to the code now. :)